# How can I test the reliability of wireless connections through a router?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I know about [iperf3](https://iperf.fr) for measuring throughput, but I would like to stress test my router and measure how reliable wireless connections are over extended periods of time, to eliminate the router as a cause of wireless speakers occasionally stopping playback for no discernible reason.

If I understand correctly, ping (ICMP) isn't the right tool for this, because it only sends very little data. What I'd want to simulate is traffic at X Mbps for Y hours (where X is, say, half the router's advertised bandwidth), and see at least how many packets have been dropped. Ideally, I'd also see a distribution of latencies, similar to what [ab](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) provides, e.g. X% of the packets made it in < Y ms.

Some of the speakers I have use [Play-Fi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTS_(sound_system)#Play-Fi), others use a proprietary protocol over Wi-Fi, but all speakers support DLNA.

Comment: If you have no way of having the speaker confirm it's recieved the packets (such as iperf3) then you've got no clear way of testing it.

If you just want to test the router, then iperf3 is the perfect tool to do so...

Comment: Oh, and you'd want the -b option in iperf3 -- -b, --bandwidth n[KM] Set target bandwidth to n bits/sec (default 1 Mbit/sec for UDP, unlimited for TCP). If there are multiple streams (-P flag), the bandwidth limit is applied separately to each stream. You can also add a ’/’ and a number to the bandwidth specifier. This is called "burst mode". It will send the given number of packets without pausing, even if that temporarily exceeds the specified bandwidth limit.

Comment: And -t for setting how long to test for (it's in seconds by default).